# 3d conditional with a present perfect

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

The sentence is:

> She **might have fainted** three times **if** she**’d seen** what you **have** (seen) today.

Shouldn’t it be *what you had seen* because of the sequence-of-tenses rule?

Comment: The mention of "Third Conditional form" indicates that there may already be an answer on ELL.

Answer (score 2):

There is no one "sequence of tenses" rule; there's a whole bunch of "rules" governing how verbforms are aligned to reflect a whole bunch of different time relationships.

There is, moreover, a whole bunch of common conditional constructions which do not conform, formally or semantically, to the canonical three. But that's not in play here. This sentence does in fact exhibit canonical "3rd conditional" form:

> She might have fainted ... if she had seen X

But X in this case is a subordinate clause, which is not involved in the conditional construction. It may be cast in any form which expresses its factuality; it may even employ a future reference:

> She might have fainted ... if she had seen **what I am going to write tomorrow**.

Without more context we have no way of knowing when exactly 'her' hypothetical fainting might have occurred: this clause may refer to an occasion five minutes ago or yesterday or a year ago or a thousand years ago. What we do know is that it was in the past, while what 'you' saw is referred to as something fresh in 'your' experience. We have no reason to think the verbforms are misused.